# Switch between two outputs on a timer

Tags: led, output

I am new to electronics and have used flashing LEDs with chips built into them before now, but this time I am going to be using 8 LEDs total, and want them to stay in sync.

I want to have a setup where the output switches between two different outputs which each have four LEDs every 1/2 second (or thereabouts).

[image: Very very very basic electronics diagram :P]
PS: I know I have to have resistors because the LEDs need 3.3v, and ill provide them 9v. I'll be using 240 ohm resistors when I build the project

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why 9v?  If you can, you would be better starting with a lower voltage.

Comment: What type of blinking LEDs do you use? Why do not you use simple LEDs and a 555 timer circuit for example?

Comment: Yes, there are a million ways to do this. To determine which ones are suited for your case, we need to know a lot more about your project. Why two times four leds? (Why not three or five?) Why every 1/2 seconds? Why 9V? Why do you want them to stay in sync? How bright do they need to be? How long does the battery need to last? What is your budget? What is your space and weight constraints? Does it have to be waterproof? And so on and so forth. You have to give the details, or better yet, the context, if you want to receive good answers. What exactly are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: One of the million ways Dampmaskin mentions, that might be interesting to someone new to electronics, is to use a microcontroller such as a small Atmel or PIC microcontroller. One way to get started with microcontrollers is to use an Arduino with the Arduino IDE (see "[blink](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink)" *sketch* and variants). If you plan on getting into electronics more seriously you *might* be best to start with a bare microcontoller on protoboard and using the chip-vendor's toolsets and learning resources (I wouldn't but YMMV).

Comment: @HandyHowie just the simplest way for the product I'm adding these lights to, otherwise I'd need 2 AAs which are .3v under the recommended voltage.

Comment: @AltAir to clarify, I used to use blinking LEDs but I found that they easily got out of sync. That's one of my ideas but the pinout for the 555 timers that I've found confuse me :P

Comment: @Dampmaskin... 2x4 LEDs because that's what fits in acrylic laser cut mould I'm making. 1/2 second because that's about the speed the lights flash on a police car. 9v is negotiable but I though that was the best for the use case. Stay in sync because they're going to be used on a mini police light bar. I want them fairly bright, but not blinding. Not using this often so about 10-20 hrs mins. Budget is about £10. Unsure about my space constraints as my teacher is unsure whether our project size is A4 or A3. Doesn't have to be waterproof.

Comment: @DavidWheatley surely there are more other options than 2 AAs, for example 3 AAs.  That would give you 4.5v and less losses than 9v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 3.3V I assume you are using blue LEDs.

The most efficient blue LED is a Cree XPEBBL-L1 $1.20 (single qty)
This LED will operate at 10mA up to 500mA.  It is fairly bright at 10mA.

---

**Four Cree Blue XPE LEDs @ 10mA**

[image]

9V battery is a very poor choice.  A 3.6V Li-ion would be much more efficient. Do not use off brand, no name batteries as they generally do not have the advertised mAh capacity.  Panasonic is a good choice e.g [Panasonic 3350mAh 18650 Li-ion 3.7v Battery NCR18650B $7](https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidsa/files/ncr18650b.pdf)

Resistors are very inefficient and the brightness will dim as the battery discharges.

You have limited space so a small Constant Current Regulator(CCR) with an enable pin would would do very well.  It will keep the brightness constant as the battery discharges.  A Li-ion will drop from 4.2V to 3.0V as it discharges.

---

On-Semi's CAT4004A an eight pin (2x2mm and 3 x 3mm packages) has four channels and a Rset pin to set the power on current. LEDs can be adjusted between 2mA to 40mA with 1.3v logic level signal.

LED Current for all 4 channels set by External Resistor and turned off and on with a single Enable pin.

[On-Semi CAT4004A Datasheet, 50 mV dropout at 20 mA, $1](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CAT4004A-D.PDF)

[image: On-Semi CAT4004A]

**A circuit with the above components would run about 
90 hours @ 40mA or 335 hours @ 10mA**

---

```
8 LEDs    $9.50 
Battery   $7.00
2 CAT4004 $2.00
          -----  
         $13.95 ≈ £10
```

A µController to turn them off and on would be about $0.50

Using less efficient LEDs and lower capacity battery would cut the cost considerably.

Comment: How would I set the chip to switch the LEDs on and off? Could I use a 555 timer instead?

Comment: You can use a 555.  I'd use a cheap  µController but I have the development tools to program them.  However you generate the off/on signal, it gets connected to the ENable/DIMmer pin.

Comment: I'm really new and have never tried something like this before. All I have is the battery connection. Could I use a 555 timer? I've read that this is the easiest way to do it, and it will automatically switch between outputs.